# How can I operate two terminal windows each configured for a different Terraform workspace in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, terraform

I am experimenting with Terraform Workspaces using Pycharm on my Mac. I initialized Terraform in a directory in which I have a basic working configuration that sets up a VPC with an EC2 instance on AWS.

I created a new workspace with `terraform workspace new testws` and now I want to switch back and forth between the `default` workspace and the newly created `testws` workspace without using `terraform workspace select <workspace_name>` every time.

In order to do that, I opened the terminal window inside Pycharm and split it into two terminals. The problem is that when I change workspaces in one terminal window using `terraform workspace select <workspace_name>` the other terminal also switches to that workspace's context.

Terraform documentation on using workspaces [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch the workspace with `terraform workspace select <workspace_name>`, terraform will change it in the `environment` file in `.terraform/`.

Each new terminal window will read the same variable from `.terraform/environment`.

In the documentation link you postet it is mentioned at [workspace-internals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html#workspace-internals)